# Gray bar on the bottom after following a navigation link in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui, eventkit

[image]

Hello.  I am learning SwiftUI, and I have come across an annoying problem.

What I am trying to do:  Write a program which does various time-related things which Apple’s software doesn’t do, e.g., give dates and times in calendars not built into macOS/iOS/etc.  After creating a list of running clocks in various calendars/locales/locations, I decided to tap into EventKit and EventKitUI to bring evens from Calendar.app into my app.  I succeeded in getting EventKit to report a particular day’s events, and to keep the UI comprehensible, I added a tab bar and have clocks and events in separate tabs, each tab having its own navigation stack.  Now I want to make it possible to use EventKitUI to view and edit details of events.  Apple doesn’t have anything in SwiftUI to deal directly with EKEvent objects, so I created a wrapper for EKEventViewController, and it actually worked.  But there is a weird side effect.  Above the tab bar, you will notice a light gray rectangle.  Xcode describes this thing as:

```
<_UIVisualEffectSubview: 0x11c5c0b80; frame = (0 0; 770 100); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x6000003848a0>>
```

It also extends behind the tab bar.  Once it appears, it sticks around even when I return to the main events view.  It is confined to the events tab; it doesn’t ever appear in the clocks tab.

Relevant code for the navigation link (which seems to me about as simple and unproblematic as possible):

```
            NavigationLink(destination: ASAEKEventView(event: event as! EKEvent)) {
                ASAEventCell(event: event, primaryRow: self.primaryRow, secondaryRow: self.secondaryRow, timeWidth: self.timeWidth, timeFontSize: self.timeFontSize, eventsViewShouldShowSecondaryDates: self.eventsViewShouldShowSecondaryDates)
            }
```

My question:  how can I get rid of the light gray rectangle?  Thanks in advance for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: please read and consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and please keep in mind that the best way to ask a question is to give us reproducable copyable code, which reproduces the problem and which we can try out ourselves, not just 3 lines which say at least nothing....

Comment: Sorry.  I found a way around my problem (presenting in a sheet or popover instead of simply pushing on the navigation stack).  I will try to be more specific next time I post a question.